# PyPi - muncres3 vs. muncres

Tags: python, hungarian-algorithm

I'm using muncres3 in my project (it implements Hungarian algorithm) I need to mark some fields as DISALLOWED as I was able in muncres. Does anyone how they have implemented this feature in muncres3, please ?

Thanks

Comment: munkres3 appears to just be the Python 3 version of munkres. Does it not work the same way?

Comment: well, I went back to munkres, as far as founded out on GitHub it is more updated and it seems like that munkres3 is not more updated and munkres went to be only suitable for Python3. It's confusing naming, but it works fine :D